# Rails 1 to 2 Polymorphic

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

I'm currently having trouble implementing a 1-to-2 association, which is polymorphic. I have three models involved in this, **Rule**, **Ip** and **IpGroup**. Each **Rule** has exactly two of **Ipish**, which can be either an **Ip** or **IpGroup**. However, when loading entries from DB, the **ipish_from** and **ipish_to** always remain **nil**. Also, don't get confused by `class_name: "Ipish"`, there is no explicit class in the project named "Ipish"; in an older version of the project it was not polymorphic and it said `class_name: "Ip"`.

```
class Rule
  belongs_to :ipish_from, class_name: "Ipish", foreign_key: :ipish_id_from, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :ipish_to, class_name: "Ipish", foreign_key: :ipish_id_to, polymorphic: true
end

class Ip
  has_and_belongs_to_many :ip_groups
  has_many :rules_from, as: :ipish
  has_many :rules_to, as: :ipish
end

class IpGroup
  has_and_belongs_to_many :ips
  has_many :rules_from, as: :ipish
  has_many :rules_to, as: :ipish
end
```

The table in my MySQL-DB currently looks like this

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ rules                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ ipish_id_from: int       +
+ ipish_type_from: string  +
+ ipish_id_to: int         +
+ ipish_type_to: string    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Any tips on how I should be doing this? I must use polymorphic associations for this. Also, this problem does only exist because of how the objects are related; I know how the "standard" polymorphism works. Maybe Rails expects a different column name to determine the **Type** of an **Ipish** object? I haven't found anything that says how to change what Rails expects, unfortunately.

Comment: Could you elaborate what is Ipish?

Comment: Of course, it's the name of the polymorphic object, kind of like an abstract class. It is not explicitly defined as a class, it just ties `Ip` and `IpGroup` together, so both can be used as objects representing `ipish_from` and `ipish_to`. To achieve this, the classes must have the `as: :ipish` in the `has_many` making use of the polymorphic assocations. Normally, polymorphics are named `...able`, for example `Commentable`, but calling it `Ipable` kinda made no sense.